# SQL Azure Migration Wizard - how to re-migrate

Tags: sql, azure, migration, synchronization, wizard

Once you have successfully migrated a local SQL Server database up to SQL Azure, how can you use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard to re-migrate (or sync if you will) the database?

I get a number of errors, and the migration hangs when I attempt to re-run the wizard.

Comment: One possibility I've thought of that seems to work "okay" is to have "Prod", "Staging" and "Dev" versions of the SQL Azure database.  Then, within the Azure portal, delete the "Dev" or "Staging" databases... re-create them (same names). Then re-migrate the local development database with the Azure "dev" database using the SQL Azure Migration Wizard tool.  That usually goes well, and smooth.  Then - use the good old SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare tools to sync between the SQL Azure databases.  Thoughts? Too "hacky"??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the SQL Azure Migration Wizard will re-migrate/sync data.

To sync data, I you have a few options to consider:

- SQL Data Sync - this is currently in Preview status.  It'll sync SQL Server to SQL Database, or SQL Database to SQL Database.  You can find some more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456371.aspx
- Red Gate's SQL Data Compare - this tool should work well with SQL Database as well.  I don't believe it has a scheduling component out-of-the box, but you could probably wire that up.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: We have recently purchased Red Gate's Comparison Bundle, and do use the SQL Data Compare tool... but in a development cycle, the schema is generally what is changing often and needs to be sync'd up to SQL Azure.  SQL Compare does a fantastic job, but has many issues when syncing from "normal" SQL Server databases up to SQL Azure.